# Morphisms of action group and continuity

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a profinite group, $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ two finite topological spaces with a continuous action group of $\mathbf{G}$ on them.
If $\mathbf{G}$ is finite, is this true that every action group morphism from $\mathbf{X}$ to $\mathbf{Y}$ is also necessarily continuous?

I tried but i don't know how to prove this. I guess i have to use the fact that $\mathbf{G}$ is discrete but i didn't get very far. I feel like i'm missing something obvious.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Think of $G$ acting trivially on $X$ and $Y$ then an action group morphism is, in this case, any function from $X$ to $Y$. Whence, if the property you are claiming were true then any function from $X$ to $Y$ would be continuous. If $X$ is in bijection with $Y$ this would mean that any bijective function from $X$ to $Y$ is a homeomorphism... which is obviously false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like i interpreted wrong what my book was saying.